# How to take in text/character argument without quotes

Tags: r, function, text, character, quotes

Sorry if the question is unclear. Feel free to change it.

So basically I am trying to find a way so that text/character string arguments for a function don't require quotes.

```
foo  = function(x, y, data){
    n1 = length(data[,x])
    n2 = length(data[,y])
    cat(n1, n1)
 }
```

If I use the following code

```
data(survey)
foo(Sex, Fold, survey)
```

I will get an error message. But if I use the following:

```
foo("Sex", "Fold", survey)
```

or

```
foo(1, 5, survey)
```

the function will give me what I want. So I wonder if there is any way to construct the function such that I won't need to use quotes around the column names. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need _both_ `foo(Sex, Fold, survey)` and `foo(1, 5, survey)` to work with the same function?

Comment: Yes. If that's possible, it would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this will work with the symbols:

```
foo  = function(x,y, data){
    n1 <- length(eval(substitute(x),data))
    n2 <- length(eval(substitute(y),data))
    cat(n1,n2)  
}
```

If you wanted this to work with quoted variable names and integer indices as well, you could simply check `x` and `y` at the start with some simple `if-else` branching.

But it comes with the standard warning that the `eval(substitute())` idiom can be dangerous to use. (You may not always be able to anticipate how it *won't* work in some cases, and you may not *realize* when it isn't working.)

Comment: Could you mention at least a few of the cases when/how it might not work?

Comment: @civilstat The most common case I’ve seen is when dealing with objects involving formulas, where the environment attached to the formula is important and so if you’re not very careful about preserving the info about that environment the eval() won’t work or give very unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you. Formulas seem like a natural use case for eval(substitute()) at first glance, so it's very helpful to know that's problematic!

Comment: @civilstat Well, you're right, `model.frame` uses `eval`, for instance (but not substitute in all cases). It's often just that people forget that `substitute` _also_ has an environment argument, and so when they try to cook up their own way to, say, re-use formulas passed along as arguments to functions, things can get very complicated very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

That has to do with the indices `[]` argument to a data frame.

When you say DF[,x] it's telling R which column to choose from DF. If x is the literal column "Sex" from DF, it will tell R that you want all the columns that are in the vector `DF$Sex`.

So if you use "Sex"/"Fold" or `1,5`, then your function should be as is. If you want to use `Sex` and `Fold`, then your function should be:

```
foo = function(x,y,data){
n1 <- length(x)
n2 <- length(y)
cat(n1,n2)
}
```